# Wi-Fi not working on mid 2014 MacBook Pro with Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, 15.10, broadcom, macbook

I'm trying to triple boot OSX, Windows 10 and Ubuntu and I'm having a few issues with Ubuntu. So far everything seems to work except for the Wi-Fi. The wired connections seem to work, however, as the MacBook doesn't have an ethernet port (lol I know), I can only get a network connection through my phone right now.

I have tried updating my drivers and looked at multiple "supposed" fixes on the web and nothing works. If anybody has any advice or suggestions as what I can do next that would be great.

I don't know if matters but here are some specs:

- OS: El Capitan
- CPU: 2.8 GHz Intel Core i5

This is the network Controller I am using:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
   Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:0112]
 Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: You need to run `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Comment: You could do it in GUI too in Additional Drivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because MacBook Pro uses a Broadcom Wifi driver which is not open source and so you will have to download and install it yourself.

To do so, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe wl
```

Note: for this a working internet connection is required.

Source: [WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) from the official Ubuntu documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue when trying Ubuntu 20.04 (booted from USB) on Macbook Air (Mid 2014). Broadcom Wifi not recognized.

However, the option 'enable proprietary drivers´ is presented during the proper install process. Checking that box in the Ubuntu installer did the trick: wifi works, no need for any manual installs.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, to get an internet over the cable from your iPhone you can use usb-a to lightning wire.

1. Visit packages.ubuntu.com
2. Find there ipheth-utils
3. Download it:

   - select amd64
   - copy the address of any mirror (ex. cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu)
   - paste it to the address bar (do not press enter)
   - add the path of subcatalog pool/universe/i/ipheth/ to the mirror address
   - Download the package ipheth-utils_1.0+git20111206-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
4. Copy it to flash drive
5. Connect flash drive to mac running ubuntu
6. Copy file to any directory
7. Open terminal in that directory
8. Run command sudo dpkg -i *.deb (if there is only one .deb package in this directory)
9. Restart ubuntu

Now your wired connection works using connected iPhone and its personal hotspot.